# as.Date seems not te be working with excel dates

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hi I have this input file
http://www.mediafire.com/file/a4yda7zmwvpd9zi/data.xlsx/file

MIN and MAX columns are Date type in the xls file and also after as.Date the Class is Date, the type is double as it should be.. but when I run the following code

```
library(ggplot2)
library(readxl)

out <- read_xlsx("C:/data.xlsx")

out

out$MIN <- as.Date(out$MIN)
out$MAX <- as.Date(out$MAX)
class(out$MIN)

#out$MIN <- as.Date(out$MIN, format = "%d/%m/%Y")

library(dplyr)

out %>% 
  group_by(SEX) %>% 
  tidyr::gather(key, value, -SEX) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(SEX, value)) + 
  geom_line(aes(color = SEX)) + 
  coord_flip() + 
  scale_y_date(breaks = c(out$MIN, out$MAX)) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
out
```

I keep getting the error `date_trans works with objects of class Date only`

I tried different formats.. even changed the excel original data types to different date formats but keep getting the same error..

Comment: Read the *Other Applications* section of the *R Help Desk* article in R News 4/1 -- https://cran.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2004-1.pdf

Comment: Try `out %>% 
  tidyr::gather(key, value, -one_of(c("ID", "SEX"))) `. You're using `gather` on various columns and then the types get dropped for `Date` in the `value` column as it also contains other variables. But you'd need to explain what is the purpose then it'd be easier to help with final solution.

Comment: The final purpose is to plot for each ID (in the y axis) a line that goes from MIN to MAX (therefore dates are in the x axis) and the color of the line should depend on SEX, so should be red lines for WOMAN and blue lines for MAN...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
out %>% 
  tidyr::gather(key, value, -one_of(c("ID", "SEX"))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(ID, value, group = ID)) + 
  geom_line(aes(color = SEX)) + 
  coord_flip() + 
  scale_y_date(breaks = seq(min(out$MIN), max(out$MAX), by = "year")) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

Though I doubt the usefulness of such charts, and how you'd solve the scale for dates (I made a sequence of years from the minimum to maximum), but that's up to you.

Comment: Thanks!! Is there a way to keep only the horizontal lines? I'm trying to show that women and men do activities that have a duration.. it is like a gantt, each ID is one person executing an activity during two dates thanks a lot for your patience

Comment: You're welcome! It is, you can use the `ID` as `group` in `aes`. See my edit. Consider accepting and/or upvoting if it helped.